# In azure api management how to call using Virtual IP

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

How to call an API published in azure API management using Virtual IP of API management. I know that we'll get VIP in azure api management and how to call using  using that VIP, as port number is not known.

Answer (score 0):

Api management does not respond on IP address. The bindings are only setup for specific host names configured on the service.

What is the scenario you want me to call on an IP address?

Comment: no I just wanted to know is there any solution. In case if an application doesn't accepts hostname then.. how to resolve that one.